# Prolog program find sum of series and it's exponentiation

Tags: prolog

Sorry for the strange title of my question.
I just start learning prolog and i have come into a problem and it's calculating the sum of series of numbers and it's exponentiation , For example,
If i entered the number 3 , Prolog should output -> 3^2 + 2^2 + 1^2 = ?.
The only thing that worked for me was printing the numbers but not the final result

```
calculation(X):-
     X>0,write(X),
     (
        X=\=1 -> write('^2 + '),Result is X-1,calculation(Result);
        write('^2 =')      
     ).
```

I did try some methods but all failed , Any help .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write as follows:

```
  calculation(X) :-
       calculation(X, 0).           


  calculation(X, Result):-
         X >= 1 ->
         (
         writef('%w^2 + ', [X]), 
         X1 is X - 1,
         Result1 is (2 ^ X) + Result,!,
         calculation(X1, Result1)
         )
         ;
         writef('1^2 = %w',[Result]).
```

Comment: Hi Anton Danilov, Thanks for help but it did give me the same result as mine , calculation(2) -> 2^2+2^1= .   while it should print 2^2+2^1=6

Comment: Hi @Striker Try now.

Comment: Hi @Anton Danilov , I'm afraid that it it's still the same result , Printing 3^2 + 2^2 + 1^2 = , Instead of 3^2 + 2^2 + 1^2 = 14. https://imgur.com/BNEzCLq

Comment: @Striker Try now

Comment: Yeah it worked , Thank you @Anton Danilov , You really helped me out